# Solve the integral $\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3x}{\tan^3x+\cot^3x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

**Question**

Solve the integral,$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3x}{\tan^3x+\cot^3x} dx$$

**Attempt**

I converted the equation in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ using the definition of $\tan(x)$ and $\cot(x)$, and then applied the substitution $t=\sin(x)$, however, this has proved itself to be quite a difficult integral to resolve in and of itself.

I would be great full for any suggestions of a more compact method. Any hints would be also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes i tried that too but still its gets complicated

Comment: By reasons of symmetry, you have to (instead), interpret the (improper) integral as $$2 \times \lim_{a \to 0} \int_a^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^3(x)}{\tan^3(x) + \cot^3(x)}dx.$$  When I made the $t = \sin(x)$ substitution, I then followed it with a $u = t^2 \implies du = 2tdt$ substitution.  If I made no mistake, then this resulted in the integral of a rational function, whose denominator is an irreducible 2nd degree polynomial.  This should be conquerable by partial fractions.  Again, if I made no analytical errors, I strongly suspect that this exactly represents the intent of the problem composer.

Comment: yes i did the same, we get a four degree polynomial in denominator.But I am assuming there must be some alternate compact way.Thanks for your effort

Comment: Yes, you get a 4 degree polynomial in the denominator.  However, if I am not mistaken, the coefficient of the $t^3$ and $t^1$ terms should both $= 0.$  Further, the numerator should have form $2(Rt^3 - St^5)dt = (Rt^2 - St^4)2tdt.$  Therefore, the fraction yields very nicely to a $t^2 = u$ substitution.

Comment: absolutely correct

Comment: If I am not mistaken then numerator is even degree polynomial in t too

Answer (score 7):

Integrate as follows
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3x}{\tan^3x+\cot^3x} dx\\
=& \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3x+ \cos^3x}{\tan^3x+\cot^3x} dx
= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{(\sin x+ \cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x)}{(\tan x+ \cot x)(\tan^2x+\cot^2x-1)} dx\\
=& \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{(\sin x+ \cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x)(\sin x\cos x)^3}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x} dx\\
 =& \ \frac14\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{(\sin x+ \cos x)(2-\sin 2x)\sin^32x}{4-3\sin^22x} dx\>\>\>\>\>\>\>t= \sin x-\cos x\\
=& \ \frac14\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(1+t^2)(1-t^2)^3}{4-3(1-t^2)^2} dt
= \int_{-1}^1 \left( \frac{t^4}{12}+\frac1{36}+\frac{3t^2-1}{9(3t^4-6t^2-1)} \right)dt\\
=& \ \frac4{45}+\frac{2^{3/2}}{3^{9/4} }
\left( \tan^{-1}\sqrt{2\sqrt3+3}- \tanh^{-1}\sqrt{2\sqrt3-3}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: +1 : sharp.....

Comment: Thanks, I solved by this method too but I assumed that there may be some alternate compact way

Answer (score 3):

Clear
$$ \int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3x}{\tan^3x+\cot^3x} dx=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3x}{\tan^3x+\cot^3x} dx. $$
Let
$$ I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3x}{\tan^3x+\cot^3x}dx. \tag1$$
Then
$$ I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\cos^3x}{\tan^3x+\cot^3x}dx. \tag2$$
Adding (1) to (2) gives
\begin{eqnarray}
2I&=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}{\tan^3x+\cot^3x} dx\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{(\sin x+\cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x)}{(\tan x+\cot x)(\tan^2x+\cot^2x-1)} dx\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3 x\cos^3 x(\sin x+\cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x)}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x-\sin^2x\cos^2x} dx\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3 x\cos^3 x(\sin x+\cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x)}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x} dx\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^4 x\cos^3 x}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x} dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3 x\cos^4 x}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x} dx-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^5 x\cos^4 x}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x} dx-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^4 x\cos^5 x(1-\sin x\cos x)}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x} dx\\
&=&2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^4 x\cos^3 x}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x} dx-2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^5 x\cos^4 x}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x} dx\\
&=:&2J_1-2J_2.
\end{eqnarray}
Note that, under $t=\sin x$,
\begin{eqnarray}
J_1&=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^4 x\cos^3 x}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x} dx\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^4 x\cos^2 x}{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x} d\sin x\\
&=&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^4(1-t^2)}{1-3t^2(1-t^2)} dt
\end{eqnarray}
which is not hard to handle by partial fractions. You can do the same thing for $J_2$. I omit the details.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same.But I thought that there may be some alternate compact way